# CORS Policy error while trying to use axiom from react js to send Post API

Tags: python, reactjs, api, flask

While trying to make a post Axios API call from React js to Python flask API i am getting CORS policy error as

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:4000/testing' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Can anyone please guide i am using below API call from react js :

```js
const headers = { 
    'Authorization': 'Bearer my-token',
    'My-Custom-Header': 'foobar'
};
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/testing')
.then(console.log('OK'));

event.preventDefault();
```

As i am new to react js and learning need some guidance.

I have tried using proxy in package.json file of my project

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled CORS in flask?

```
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
.
.
.
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS']='Content-Type'
```

Comment: Hello Areeb thanks this worked . API is returning the output now thanks for help

Comment: I am again getting the same error when i am trying to change and add another API for inserting in to database .from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
app= Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS']='Content-Type';
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET','POST'])
def test():
    if request.method=='POST':  
        userDetails=request.form    
        name=userDetails['name'];
        return 'API Test Hit .'

React JS code  :
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/test',name_data,{headers})
       .then(response=>console.log(response.data));